# Qt: No defined slots show up in Signal & Slot Editing

Tags: qt

I have declared three slots in my `mainwindow.h` and given their definitions in the implementation file. Here is the MainWindow class:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

signals:
    void nextImage(int direction);

private slots:
    void updateImage(void);
    void cameraControl(void);
    void cameraStart(void);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    CMUCamera *camera;
    ImageProcessing *process;
    RenderImage *renderImage;
    bool saveImgFlg;
    QString path;
};
```

Going to mainwindow.ui, I have designed a menu bar for the user interface. There are three QActions, as shown in the figure below: 
[image]

Then, I do the signal and slot editing. But the defined slots (`udpateImage`, `cameraStart` and `cameraControl`) in the header file do not appear in the slot list, as shown in the figure below:

[image]

Are there any other steps I missed here or is there something I did wrong? It is also noted `QMainWindow`, in the framework of which these slots should show up, I guess, is also not displayed in the list.

Comment: To my knowledge custom slots never show in the designer's Signal and Slot editor. You did not do anything wrong. You just have to connect your signal and slot normally using `connect()`.

Comment: I don't think so. I have another written project that has private user-defined slots in the header file, and those slots can be looked up in such a slot list. I just want to know why how that can be done.

Comment: Does this help? https://forum.qt.io/topic/800/solved-how-to-see-custom-slot-in-signal-slot-editor/2

Comment: Try making the slots public, and see if that helps. It'd make sense that Designer doesn't show private slots.

Comment: @hyde: there is no any difference for setting public slots.

Comment: Then, `MainWindow` in the signal-slot connection editor refers to an object with name `MainWindow`, right? Might be less confusing if you rename that to `mainwindow` or something. Then make sure it really is of type `MainWindow`. It looks like Designer thinks `MainWindow` object is not `MainWindow` type, but plain `QMainWindow`.

Comment: @hyde: That is an object. It is selected from a drop-down list of Receiver.

Comment: The slot is possibly not showing up due to the difference in arguments (`triggered()` vs `updateImage(void)`). Try removing the `void` argument?

Comment: @Aditya: I have solved the problem, as you can see my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

I know why that happens. For adding those custom slots, in addition to defining them in header and implementation files, they also should be added in priori by right clicking the `QMainWindow`, going to `change signals and slots` and manually adding them in the slot panel.  This way is simpler than to code signal&slots.

A similar question has been reported here: [my slots don't appear in the signal slot editor](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/26196-my-slots-don-t-appear-in-the-signal-slot-editor)

Comment: It seems comfortable for a permanent connection. I guess the programmatic connection is versatile with being able to connect and disconnect as per the need.